# How to do multi authorization?

Tags: authorization, permissions, multisig

I have a question, assume an account named user with a permission @active, and is authorized to bob@active and alice@active, if I want to send a transfer action, do I need all the authorization in my action? like user@active,alice@active,bob@active

`"authorization": [
    {
     "actor": "user",
     "permission": "active"
    },
    {
     "actor": "bob",
     "permission": "active"
    },
    {
     "actor": "alice",
     "permission": "active"
    }
   ]`

or just use bob and alice like below.

 `"authorization": [
    {
     "actor": "bob",
     "permission": "active"
    },
    {
     "actor": "alice",
     "permission": "active"
    }
   ]`

because I found that the transfer action need the user@active permission.

Answer (score 1):

This article  have a very detailed explanation regarding multisig usage on EOS.

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-multisig-tutorial